# Server with virtualisation?

Tags: server

I am considering making a Ubuntu server based on the Intel NUC product category. I recently made a Ubuntu server in a virtual machine on an old MacBook and I very much liked the idea of being able to easily and securely update the server software this way because I could make sure that the server was turned on most of the time.

Do any of you know if it is very resource intensive to run a server in a virtual machine rather than only running the server OS? I would of course not use the desktop OS for "conventional" stuff.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better continue with virtual machine IMHO. because If you have multiple services that are very much important to run then in the matter of security you can use different VM's for different services.

so what you might get from my suggestion ?

1  . If your server failed/bricked with something we dont know then you must down your server for hours but If you had it in a VM then simply you can move the VM from one machine to another machine.

in a single sentence I mean to say exactly " Migration"

2
  . If you have multiple services to Run then you must have multiple VM's so that even one machine got interruption( may be from black hats) then other services wont get any problem.

hope that helps you a bit.